# GoogleMaps and Location API on Android - MyLocation (blue dot on the map) updating faster than onLocationChanged() callback?

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, location

I'm working with GoogleMaps and Google Play Services Location API in my app.

I have configured my LocationRequest so that the `onLocationChanged(Location location)` interface callback is called every 5 seconds. So far so good.

In that callback, I simply update my circle, to always be centered at my last known location.

When I run the app, If I'm still, there is no problem. But when I'm at a car for example, the blue dot is updating much faster (4 times faster aprox.) then the circle.

I would say that the circle's code block is fine, because it is indeed updating every 5 seconds. But why my location (the blue dot) is updating much faster? How can my circle also be updated whenever the blue dot is?

Comment: Can't you just change onLocationChanged to update faster, like 3 seconds?

Comment: Yes, I did that, thanks. But, If I set the update to be every 5 secs, why the blue dot is updating faster?